# How to get API key for Alchemy Academy?

Tags: android, api, ibm-watson, watson, alchemy

How can I get API key for Alchemy Academy? Thanks

```
AlchemyLanguage service = new AlchemyLanguage();
service.setApiKey("????");
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put(AlchemyLanguage.TEXT, UserInputSymptoms);
CombinedResults combinedResults = service.getCombinedResults(params).execute();
List<Keyword> relationObject = combinedResults.getKeywords();

for (Keyword relation: relationObject){
    System.out.println(relation.getText());
    extractedSymptoms_List.add(relation.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated [in the developer documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemy-language/api/v1/#introduction)

- Log in to Bluemix and go to the [AlchemyAPI service page](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/alchemyapi/).
- Click the "Create" button.
- Click the "Service Credentials" button from the AlchemyAPI page in your [Bluemix dashboard](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/dashboard/) to view your API key.